# RewriteRule with flag [L] stopping caching?

Tags: mod-rewrite, http-caching

I use server management software plesk with apache and nginx. I set in apache and nginx a expired header for javascript files for one year. That's working. I can see one year for "expires" in header.

Now I want access javascript and php files with a rewrite (without redirect).

**APACHE**

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType text/javascript A31556952

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule fake/(.+\.(?:js|php))$ original/$1 [L]
```

**NGINX**

```
location ~* ^/(.*\.js)$ {
    try_files $uri @fallback;

    expires 1y;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
}
```

That RewriteRule is working. I can access this files, but the "expires" header in "fake/file.js" is gone. What am I doing wrong?

example.com/original/file.js = expires in one year

example.com/fake/file.js = no header for expires

**SOLUTION**
All static files are normally processing by NGINX, not apache. So set in apache this line for javascript give it a cache.

> Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31556952, public"

Flag [L] in RewriteRule must stop static files processing by nginx and ExpiresByType is ignored.

Comment: How exactly are you setting the `Expires` header? Where are you using these directives? What other directives do you have? "in apache **and** nginx" - how does Nginx fit into this? (Aside: All modern browsers use the `Cache-Control` + `max-age` header over the `Expires` header.)

Comment: Thanks, I have edit my question. Cache-Control is working, but why not ExpiresByType and why static files its not processing by nginx at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why static files its not processing by nginx at all?

Because `/fake/file.js` is no longer a "static file" (it doesn't exist), so is passed through to Apache, where it is internally rewritten to get the required  response.

> ```
> ExpiresByType text/javascript A31556952
> ```

`text/javascript` may not be the "correct" mime-type for JavaScript responses on *your server*. You need to confirm what mime-type (ie. `Content-Type` header) your server is sending back with these responses, but this would normally be `application/javascript` instead these days. In other words:

```
ExpiresByType application/javascript A31556952
```

To clarify, mod_expires `ExpiresByType` sets both the `Expires` *and* `Cache-Control: max-age` HTTP response headers. `Cache-Control: max-age` takes priority on all modern browsers. `Expires` is really only for legacy support.

> Flag [L] in RewriteRule must stop static files processing by nginx

The `L` flag simply stops the current pass of the rewrite engine on Apache. These directives themselves do not influence Nginx (which would seem to be acting as a front-end proxy).